# Overcome 70 character limit when sending non-english SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms, alphabet, 7-bit

Currently i'm using SmsManager's sendTextMessage.

Messages may contain non-english characters, but all of the characters are part of the GSM 7bit alphabet.

Is there a way to overcome the 70 chars (UTF-8) limit and create a 160 chars message? Is creating a PDU based SMS the only way to go, or this can be done in another way? I couldn't find any examples online, are there any?

Any help would be deeply appreciated...

Comment: use an online based IM and you remove the limitation. I believe with SMS this limit is set by the networks

Comment: The limit depends on message encoding. For UTF-8 drops to 70 chars. I am looking for a way to recode the message to GSM 7bit alphabet. I can create the needed 7bit byte array but i can't insert it into the message.